# How to connect a tab navigator to redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am new to redux and I need to call for an action inside the onPress method as shown here

```
const HomeTabNavigation = TabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: { screen: Profile },
    PhotoCard: { screen: PhotoCard },
    Chat: { screen: Chat }
  },
  {

    tabBarComponent: props => {
      return (
        <Header>
          <FooterTab>
            <Button
              onPress={() => {
                if (props.navigation.state.index !== 0) {
                  props.navigation.navigate("Profile");
                  this.props.setCurrentDisplayingScreen("Profile");
                }
              }}
            />


            <Button
              onPress={() => {
                if (props.navigation.state.index !== 1) {
                  props.navigation.navigate("PhotoCard");
                  this.props.setCurrentDisplayingScreen("PhotoCard");
                }
              }}
            />


            <Button
              onPress={() => {
                if (props.navigation.state.index !== 2) {
                  props.navigation.navigate("Chat");
                  this.props.setCurrentDisplayingScreen("Chat");
                }
              }}
            />

            </Button>
          </FooterTab>
        </Header>
      );
    }
  }
);

// Connect redux to call actions and receive new states
export default connect(null, actions)(HomeTabNavigation);
```

As shown in the code I want to call an action when tapping on the tab bar icon to navigate to another tab.

If I do that I get the following error:
"invariant violation: this navigator has both navigation and container props, so it is unclear if it should own its own state"